# A hash using lambdas without relying on conditionals or enumerators

Tags: ruby, hash, lambda

If I were to have a list like so of accepted aliases and root names for basic colors:

```
coloraliases = {
  ["red", "crimson", "auburn", "rose", "maroon", "burgundy"] => "red",
  ["blue", "teal", "aqua", "azure", "cobalt"] => "blue",
  ["green", "emerald", "absinthe", "avocado", "lime"] => "green",
  ["yellow", "banana", "lemon", "gold", "citrine"] => "yellow"
}
```

I couldn't just do this:

```
coloraliases["crimson"]
#=> "red"
```

I'm trying to coax this behavior like so:

```
basecolor = lambda do |str|
  x = nil
  coloraliases.each do |keys, value|
    if keys.include?(str)
      x = value
      break
    end
  end# of coloraliases hash
  x
end
```

which should work as expected.

Am wondering if there are any more elegant ways to do this, specifically ways not involving conditional blocks or even enumerators. Ternary operators are ok or better because they're compact but still not preferable because they're conditionals.

Comment: All I can think of is the hash selector pattern: https://www.codemy.net/posts/hash-selector-pattern
Which is pretty much like doing coloraliases['crimson']...

Comment: What's wrong with having each of the keys individually map to the corresponding base color?  Which I now see @sawa suggested seconds before I saved this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your hash design is wrong. You are not using it in a way a hash is supposed to be used. It should be:

```
coloraliases = {
  "red" => "red",
  "crimson" => "red",
  "auburn" => "red",
  "rose" => "red",
  "maroon" => "red",
  "burgundy" => "red",
  "blue" => "blue",
  "teal" => "blue",
  "aqua" => "blue",
  "azure" => "blue",
  "cobalt" => "blue",
  ...
}
```

And then, you would simply get:

```
coloraliases["crimson"] # => "red"
```

Comment: Frustratingly simple. Thanks